# One of my Macs suddenly fails to read U-disk

Tags: external-disk

One of my Macs suddenly fails to read my U-disk. I have restarted the machine several times it still shows "0 items, 102.11 GB available".

[image: no items]

While my other Mac can read the u-disk without any problem. How do I fix it ?

[image: u-disk]

With the comment I got from nohillside I did another test, first `cd into a folder`, then ran `open .` to open it in Finder and Finder can show it!!

But if I click its parent folder then Finder shows "0 item" again.

[image: cd into a folder]

Finder shows the folder content!

[image: Finder show a folder]

Comment: If you open Terminal on the first Mac and run `cd /Volumes/N*NAME; ls`, what do you see? If you open Disk Utility and select the drive, what do you see? Please edit the question with the results.

Comment: @nohillside sorry for the late reply. `ls` I can see everything. So it this a bug of finder?

Comment: Sounds like it is a bug in finder. Have the files accidentally been set to hidden? You can view hidden files in finder by pressing the keyboard shortcut `command`+`shift`+`.` (period). Alternatively, enter `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` in terminal. To change back to hidden files just change TRUE to FALSE in the above command... To permanently change the hidden files to be visible, you can run another command, but I forgot it ages ago, maybe google it :)

Comment: @AVelj check mu updated content, I don't think it is because of hidden files.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if your external drive has two partitions to it and you're not clicking on the correct partition? Check how many partitions your external drive has by running `diskutil list` and tell me if it's showing multiple partitions? Also in Finder's preferences, make sure to enable "External Disks" under Sidebar locations by ensuring it's a tick (✔️) and not a dash (-) in the checkbox. If this checkbox is showing a dash (-), it may suggest it is partially hiding some partitions of the external drive in the sidebar, which happens if you previously manually removed it from sidebar.

Comment: @AVelj thanks for spending time in looking into this, diskutil list shows "/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *125.3 GB   disk4
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 NO NAME                 125.3 GB   disk4s1

Comment: sidebar setting is a tick (I had checked this before I asked the question)

Comment: Hmm, I'm at a loss then, because macOS can read Windows FAT32 disk drives and it doesn't appear to have a second partition from what you've said. The only other thing I can think of is read/write permissions are blocked, but that wouldn't make sense since you can see it from terminal... The only other thing I can think of is if the files have been dragged to trash but you never emptied the trash when the USB was plugged in?

Comment: @AVelj I would assume this is just a "stupid" bug.

Comment: Hi, today I used "First Aid" in Disk Utility on it. I did not expect that would repair it but to my surprise it did! Now finder can show my u-disk again!